# C++ pointer error

Tags: c++, pointers

When I tried to compile the following C++ program:

```
//Source: C++ How To Program, Sixth Edition
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
int a;
int *aPtr;
a=7;
aPtr=&a;
std::cout<<"The address of a is: "<<&a<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"The value of aPtr is: "<<aPtr<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"The value of a is: "<<a<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"The value of *aPtr is: "<<*aPtr<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"Showing that * and & are inverses of each"
<<" other"<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"&*aPtr= "<<&*aPtr<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"*&aPtr= "<<*&aPtr<std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

I got the following error:

[image]

Any ideas on that?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest you put some more spaces in, e.g. around your operators `std::cout << "*&aPtr= " << *&aPtr < std::endl;` This would make it all easier to read!

Comment: And always compile with `g++ -Wall`...

Comment: If you can cut and paste the error as text from the console, that is much easier to read than a picture.

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas. I'm using `Cygwin` console, and cannot do that.

Comment: @Paul R. What is `-wall`? Thanks

Comment: It shows you all compiler warnings. It's usually a good way to detect code smell.

Comment: @user588855: `-Wall` enables all warnings - this can help you to catch errors a lot sooner - it should really be the default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace

```
std::cout<<"*&aPtr= "<<*&aPtr<std::endl;
```

by

```
std::cout<<"*&aPtr= "<<*&aPtr<<std::endl;
```

Just a syntax error in your code ( `<` instead of `<<` ).

Answer (score 3):

Line 15 says `*&aPtr   <   std::endl`. should be `<<` instead of `<`.

You would spot this kind of error more easily if you put spaces between operators and operants.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a simple typo in line 15. You forgot one "<" between aPTR and the endl-constant ;)

`std::cout<<"*&aPtr= "<<*&aPtr<std::endl;`

Answer (score 3):

You missed a `<` on the last line:

```
//----------------------------v here.
std::cout<<"*&aPtr= "<<*&aPtr<<std::endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the typo on line 15, where you've written `<` instead of `<<`.  The error message makes that pretty clear!

Answer (score 2):

fix this line (syntax error) (`<<` instead of `<`)

```
std::cout<<"*&aPtr= "<<*&aPtr<std::endl;
```